# LDAP query in python

Tags: python, ldap, ldap-query

I want to execute the following query in the ldap

```
ldapsearch -h hostname -b dc=ernet,dc=in -x "(&(uid=w2lame)(objectClass=posixAccount))" gidnumber
ldapsearch -h hostname -b dc=ernet,dc=in -x "(&(gidNumber=1234)(objectClass=posixGroup))" cn
```

And use the variables thus obtained. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use the [`ldap`](http://www.python-ldap.org) module. Code would look something like:

```
import ldap
l = ldap.initialize('ldap://ldapserver')
username = "uid=%s,ou=People,dc=mydotcom,dc=com" % username
password = "my password"
try:
    l.protocol_version = ldap.VERSION3
    l.simple_bind_s(username, password)
    valid = True
except Exception, error:
    print error
```

Comment: Am I crazy, or does this not answer the question? He's asking how to run a query, and you're showing him how to bind.

Comment: @mehasse: The example was intended to show common usage of the ldap module, which I think it does. If you are trying to do a query you can use the .search method on the ldap object.

Answer (score 66):

While the accepted answer does in fact show a proper way to bind to an LDAP server I do feel it didn't answer the question holistically. Here is what I ended up implementing to grab the mail and department of a user. This somewhat blends the required attributes from the original question.

```
l = ldap.initialize('ldap://ldap.myserver.com:389')
binddn = "cn=myUserName,ou=GenericID,dc=my,dc=company,dc=com"
pw = "myPassword"
basedn = "ou=UserUnits,dc=my,dc=company,dc=com"
searchFilter = "(&(gidNumber=123456)(objectClass=posixAccount))"
searchAttribute = ["mail","department"]
#this will scope the entire subtree under UserUnits
searchScope = ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE
#Bind to the server
try:
    l.protocol_version = ldap.VERSION3
    l.simple_bind_s(binddn, pw) 
except ldap.INVALID_CREDENTIALS:
  print "Your username or password is incorrect."
  sys.exit(0)
except ldap.LDAPError, e:
  if type(e.message) == dict and e.message.has_key('desc'):
      print e.message['desc']
  else: 
      print e
  sys.exit(0)
try:    
    ldap_result_id = l.search(basedn, searchScope, searchFilter, searchAttribute)
    result_set = []
    while 1:
        result_type, result_data = l.result(ldap_result_id, 0)
        if (result_data == []):
            break
        else:
            ## if you are expecting multiple results you can append them
            ## otherwise you can just wait until the initial result and break out
            if result_type == ldap.RES_SEARCH_ENTRY:
                result_set.append(result_data)
    print result_set
except ldap.LDAPError, e:
    print e
l.unbind_s()
```

Comment: Better user `search_s()` to avoid the `while 1`

Comment: To complete @Caumons comment; to avoid using while 1 do this : 
`res = l.search_s(basedn, searchScope, searchFilter, searchAttribute)`
    `print res`
    `l.unbind_s()`

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example generator for python-ldap.

The `ldap_server` is the object you get from ldap.initialize(). You will probably need to bind before calling this function, too, depending on what LDAP server you are using and what you are trying to query for. The `base_dn` and `filter_` are similar to what you've got in your command line version. The `limit` is the maximum number of records returned.

```
def _ldap_list(ldap_server, base_dn, filter_, limit=0):
    """ Generator: get a list of search results from LDAP asynchronously. """

    ldap_attributes = ["*"] # List of attributes that you want to fetch.
    result_id = ldap_server.search(base_dn, ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, filter_, ldap_attributes)
    records = 0

    while 1:
        records += 1

        if limit != 0 and records > limit:
            break

        try:
            result_type, result_data = ldap_server.result(result_id, 0)
        except ldap.NO_SUCH_OBJECT:
            raise DirectoryError("Distinguished name (%s) does not exist." % base_dn)

        if result_type == ldap.RES_SEARCH_ENTRY:
            dn = result_data[0][0]
            data = result_data[0][1]
            yield dn, data
        else:
            break
```

**Please keep in mind that interpolating user-provided values into your LDAP query is dangerous!** It's a form of injection that allows a malicious user to change the meaning of the query. See: http://www.python-ldap.org/doc/html/ldap-filter.html

Answer (score 1):

you can use the commands module, and the getoutput to parse the result of the ldap query:

```
from commands import getoutput
result = getoutput('ldapsearch -h hostname -b dc=ernet,dc=in -x "(&(uid=w2lame)(objectClass=posixAccount))"')
print result
```

you have to have ldapsearch binary installed in your system.

Comment: Using commands, when there is a Python library is never a good idea.

Comment: Some companies use custom IT commands for internal interaction with infrastructure, one may be required to use such commands to avoid getting a visit from the IT enforcement unit. "Never say never".

Comment: And some Python libraries, like the aforementioned python-ldap, have such convoluted external build requirements and no official binaries that for small tasks, it's honestly not worth the trouble to trying to bully them into working.

Comment: this solution was perfect for some quick testing.

Answer (score 1):

I cobbled this together this morning while skimming through the [documentation of the `ldap` module](https://www.python-ldap.org/en/python-ldap-3.3.0/). It can fulfil the requirements of the OP changing the filter and the other settings to his liking.

The documentation of the `ldap` module is pretty good if you understand the context (that's what took me a while). And the module is *surprinsingly easy* to use. We have a similar script written in bash using `ldapserach` that is at least 3 or 4 times longer and more complex to read.

This code accepts a partial search string (email, name, uid or part of it) and returns the results in LDIF format. The idea is to make it very simple to use for a very specific task and if possible without using flags so that my less skilled co-workers can find the relevant info quickly.

Note that this is written for an LDAP server that runs on a machine that is not accessible from outside our internal network and which is secured with 2FA authentication. It can, thus, safely accept anonymous queries. But adding user and password should be trivial.

```
   #! /usr/bin/python3
    
    ### usearch
    ### searches in the LDAP database for part of a name, uid or email and returns mail, uid, and full name
    
    import ldap
    import argparse
    import sys
    import ldif
    
    l = ldap.initialize('ldaps://your.fancy.server.url', bytes_mode=False)
    
    basedn = "dc=foo,dc=bar,dc=baz"
    
    
    ## ARGPARSE stuff!!! 
    
    parser=argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description ='searches the LDAP server', 
        usage='usearch PARTIAL_MATCH (email, name, username)',
        formatter_class = argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter)
    parser.add_argument('istr', help='searches stuffz')
    parser.print_help
    args = parser.parse_args(None if sys.argv[1:] else ['-h'])
   
   str1 = args.istr
    
    
    sfilter = "(|(sn=*{}*)(mail=*{}*)(uid=*{}*))".format(str1,str1,str1)
    attributes = ["mail","uid","cn"]
    scope = ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE
    
    r = l.search_s(basedn,scope,sfilter,attributes)
    
    ldif_writer=ldif.LDIFWriter(sys.stdout)
    
    for dn, entry in r:
        ldif_writer.unparse(dn,entry)
```

---

And as I was at it, here a version with the ldap3 module. The `argparse` part is copy-pasted. This time the output is "human readable", instead of LDIF:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3
## usearch3
## LDAP3 version 

import ldap3
import argparse
import sys

server = ldap3.Server('ldaps://foo.bar.baz')
conn = ldap3.Connection(server)
conn.bind()
basedn = 'dc=foobar,dc=dorq,dc=baz'
attribs = ['mail','uid','cn']

parser=argparse.ArgumentParser(
    description ='searches the LDAP server and returns user, full name and email. Accepts any partial entry', 
    usage='usearch3 PARTIAL_MATCH (email, name, username)',
    formatter_class = argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter)
parser.add_argument('istr', help='searches stuffz')
parser.print_help
args = parser.parse_args(None if sys.argv[1:] else ['-h'])

str1 = args.istr

sfilter = "(|(sn=*{}*)(mail=*{}*)(uid=*{}*))".format(str1,str1,str1)

conn.search(basedn,sfilter)
conn.search(basedn,sfilter,attributes = attribs)

leng = len(conn.entries)
for i in range(leng):
   
    user = conn.entries[i].uid
    fullname = conn.entries[i].cn
    email = conn.entries[i].mail
    
    print("user:\t{}\nname:\t{}\nemail:\t{}\n\n".format(user,fullname,email))
```

Comment: And yes, the .format(str1,str1,str1) looks like sh*t, but I wanted to get the LDAP part running. I actually use this script... while at the same time it was an exercise for de-rusting my Python.

Comment: the above python script worked for sometime after which it stopped giving the desired result. What could be the reason ?

Comment: @user956424 no idea, I have this running in production since October (2021). A change in your LDAP server, maybe?

Comment: figured it out that it required the LDAP password to make the necessary connection. So above statement changed as:     conn = ldap3.Connection(server,DN,'Password', auto_bind=True)

Comment: @user956424 : Yeah, I wanted to mimic the behaviour of the ldapsearch command of the OP